# How to get events when I press an item in a submenu MFC?

Tags: c++, events, mfc, contextmenu, submenu

I am creating a program like Windows Task Manager. 
The working environment is visual c ++ 6.0.

```
void CProcess01Dlg::OnRclickListCtrl(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) {
    CPoint ptInList, ptInSrceen;
    GetCursorPos(&ptInSrceen); 
    ptInList = ptInSrceen;
    m_ctrlList.ScreenToClient(&ptInList);       

    POSITION pos = m_ctrlList.GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
    int nListIndex = m_ctrlList.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);

    CMenu menu, *pMenu;
    menu.LoadMenuA(IDR_MENU1);

    CString str;
    str.Format("%d",nListIndex);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(str);

    if( 0 <= nListIndex)
    {      
        pMenu = menu.GetSubMenu(0);      
    } 
    else   
    {

    }

    pMenu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, ptInSrceen.x, ptInSrceen.y, this);
}
```

The above code is a function that handles events when an item in list control is right-clicked in MFC.

I want to add an event in the context menu when a context menu appears when I right-click an item.

Tell us how you're handling the event. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InsertMenu` and/or `AppendMenu` to add more items to the menu.

```
CMenu menu;
menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
CMenu* popup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
popup->InsertMenu(MF_STRING, MF_BYPOSITION, ID_XXX1, "Insert");
popup->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_XXX2, "Append");
popup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, ptInSrceen.x, ptInSrceen.y, this);
```

The last parameter in [`TrackPopupMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002(v=vs.85).aspx) is the handle of the window which will receives the menu messages. You just need to handle the commands in your dialog:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProcess01Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, onfilenew)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_XXX1, foo)
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CProcess01Dlg::foo()
{
    ...
}
```